# Uint8ClampedArray.from is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am getting a problem with a QR code library(JSQR) in old browser. When i start scanning it give an error message like that

```
"Uint8ClampedArray.from is not a function"  
 source: file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/jsQR.js (143)
```

and in this file at line 143 have code like this:

```
this.zero = new GenericGFPoly_1.default(this, Uint8ClampedArray.from([0]));
this.one = new GenericGFPoly_1.default(this, Uint8ClampedArray.from([1]));
```

Does anyone have idea how to fix or use alternative way for this line where is it pointing. Here is a source code:
https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR/blob/master/dist/jsQR.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace these very calls to `new Uint8ClampedArray([0])` and `new Uint8ClampedArray([1])`. That will do exactly the same, with better browser support.

```js
const a1 = Uint8ClampedArray.from([0]);
const a2 = new Uint8ClampedArray([0]);

console.log(a1);
console.log(a2);

const b1 = Uint8ClampedArray.from([1]);
const b2 = new Uint8ClampedArray([1]);

console.log(b1);
console.log(b2);
```

And if you need more from this method, you can try the [incomplete polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from#Polyfill) available at MDN.

Answer (score 1):

The browser does not know this function. Check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility). Or try something else. For example:

```
this.zero = new GenericGFPoly_1.default(this, new Uint8ClampedArray([0]));
        this.one = new GenericGFPoly_1.default(this, new Uint8ClampedArray([1]));
```